# How to manage JSON in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: json, hadoop, hdfs

How does Hadoop **HDFS** *manage* **JSON** files?

Assuming that some JSON files are stored into the HDFS and that each of these JSONs is different from the others, I would like to output a JSON created through a query. Like *MongoDB*.

For example, I show you this pseudo-code:

```
FOR EACH json IN hdfs:
    name = json.NAME
    IF json HAS this_attribute:
        x = json.this_attribute.value

CREATE A CSV THAT CONTAINS ALL INFO REQUIRED (name, x)

RETURN CSV
```

In MongoDB, to produce this output is most easy. But I'm into a project where *to use MongoDB is not possible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop/HDFS doesn't "manage" any files beyond placing their blocks.

If you want to run queries against the data, you need to use a tool like Hive, Presto, Drill, Spark, Flink, etc, or you can alter your file upload procedure to write to HBase.

> each of these JSONs is different from the others

Most query tools prefer semi-structured data, so having the keys of the JSON being similar would be best. If you really need to store random JSON objects, then using a document database like Mongo would be preferred. (Hadoop is not an alternative to Mongo)

Comment: Right! At the end, I convinced my boss to use MongoDB!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest tool for you to use with HDFS is [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).  It give you lots of rich tooling including a lot of rich file formats that perform much better than storing text information as Text, CSV or JSON.  I suggest that you investigate using file formats that are not text when working with Big Data.